# Intersection of feet of perpendicular and Centroid at the circumcircle

Tags: geometry

Consider a $\Delta ABC$ with centroid $G$ and $AH$ the altitude where $H$ is the feet of perpendicular to $BC$. Join $HG$ to meet the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ at $A'$ and $B'$. Show that either $ABCA'$ or $ABCB'$ is an Isosceles trapezium..

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Yeah, I tried bashing it, but I wanted some synthetic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D, E, F$ be the midpoints of the side $BC, CA, AB$ respectively. Perform homothety with center $G$ and coefficient $-2$. It maps triangle $DEF$ to triangle $ABC$. Moreover it maps the circumcircle of $DEF$ to the circumcircle of $ABC$. The circumcircle of $DEF$ is the nine point circle so it passes through $M$. Therefore $M$ is mapped by the homothety to say $A'$. Thus, the line $DH$, which is in fact the line $BC$, is mapped to $AA'$ and therefore $BC \, || \, AA'$. Hence $A'BCA$ is a trapezoid inscribed in the circumcircle of $ABC$ so it is isosceles.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and $A''$ be the reflection of $A$ across the vertical bisector of $AB$. It is easy to prove that $A''H$ meets $AM$ at a point which is $2/3$ of the way from $A$ to $M$, that is at $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Phantom points and complex bash.